# Python STDOUT to file with openssl subprocess

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, subprocess, stdout

I am trying to write a python script to automate the process of checking for SSL renegotiation through openSSL and output the results to a file. I have run into 2 problems.

My first problem is that the output from the initial handshake gets written to the file, however the actual renegotiation part does not. It is instead displayed on the console.

```
subprocess.call("echo \"R\" | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443", 
        shell=True, stdout=FILE)
```

My other problem (although this may be the wrong spot for it) is that I cannot get the openSSL command to work for sending the GET command.

```
subprocess.call("echo -e \"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n\" | openssl s_client -connect
        example.com:443", shell=True)
```

Again, the initial connection is set up but then openSSL exists, it does not process the GET request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for not using the python ssl wrapper?  Maybe you could get better debugging info using that.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reason to use `shell=True` for inputs. Instead, use `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`. Also, note that your request is not valid since HTTP 1.1 requires the `Host` header. Additionally, I can't think of a reason to use the command line openssl instead of the [ssl module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html).

That being said, here's a working example:

```
import subprocess

f = open('http_answer', 'w')
_,log = subprocess.Popen(
    ['openssl', 's_client', '-quiet', '-connect', 'twitter.com:443'],
    stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE
).communicate('GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
print('Output of SSL:\n' + log)
```

Comment: The SSL module doesn't give you enough control to force renegotiation in the middle of a request being sent, or at least I couldn't find a way last time I looked into it.

Comment: I did try it with both http 1.0 and 1.1 and it seems to be giving me the same result as before. The get request is still not being processed.

Edit: and I didnt use the ssl module because we use openSSL here for quite a few different tests and I wanted to keep it consistant.

Comment: @Drew If you execute the exact code posted in the answer, do you get a file `http_answer`?

Comment: Yes I do and it outputs the result of the s_client command but it does not actually process the GET request. It just stops at the handshake.

Comment: @Drew How do you know it does not process the GET request? But if the above code is not working, something is wrong with your openssl installation or certificate store. Try it in an untouched VM or chroot.

Comment: @phihag if it was processing the GET request wouldn't it write the response to the http_answer file? The http_answer file has the handshake and then says done, with no response in it.

Comment: @Drew Ooops, my mistake, sorry; I forgot the `-quiet` option. Can you retry with the updated code?

Comment: @phihag, awesome works like a charm. I know this was not in the scope of the orginal question but any idea on how i can chain a renegotiation request on to the get? I tried using `GET / HTTP/1.0 \r\nR\r\n` but it did not work.

Comment: @Drew According to the [doc](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html#CONNECTED_COMMANDS), this is not possible when `-quiet` is given. It looks like you're trying to do advanced SSL stuff. For that, I'd recommend directly using libssl. You can access native code in Python via the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that openssl s_client uses also stderr for some of the output. You need to check whether the renegotiation goes to stderr, which I believe it does, though my memory might be fading.

I've accomplished this in a different way, though not in python. I've created a process and hooked the stdin, stdout, stderr file descriptors to ones I can read/write and I actually drive the input and read the output. It is a bit more work, but you have full control over what is going on and interacting with the process. I've done this in php and the test is available online at http://netsekure.org/2009/11/tls-renegotiation-test/.

Alternatively, you can just try using python to program openssl itself, instead of using the s_client, but this is more work and I've used the previous approach.

There are two things you can be checking and you didn't make it clear which one you are interested in:

- checking whether remote server supports client initiated renegotiation
- checking whether remote server supports the secure renegotiation extension

Both of these can be simply deduced by just doing s_client and grep for the keywords applicable to both cases. It all depends on how much control/sophistication you need.

Comment: I am trying to test whether or not a server allows to client to initiate a renegotiation. You were right about the stderr. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@phihag I have made slight changes to your scrip and is working well for me.

```
import subprocess

f = open('http_answer', 'w')
_,log = subprocess.Popen(
    ['openssl', 's_client', '-quiet', '-connect', 'twitter.com:443','-sess_out', 'session.txt'],
    stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate('GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHOST: twitter.com\r\n\r\n') print('Output of SSL:\n' + log)
```

Listing the changes 
1. added 'sess_out' 'session.txt' parameters which preserves all the SSL Session paramerters which can be views using the following openssl command

```
$openssl sess_id -in test.txt -text -cert -noout
```

2. Added host information to the GET command, as the newer section respond well only with the HOST option.

   'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHOST: twitter.com\r\n\r\n'

@Drew, Its too late but I hope this is bit helpful. Thank you.